# PHP POD returns 0 affected rows after update

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on script which takes file name and update user info, here is the snippet.

```
$fname =  $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$userId = cleanString($_POST['uid']);
$sql= 'UPDATE `contacts` SET `imgpath` = ? WHERE `contact_id` = ?';
$stmt = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === false) {
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $DBH->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$fname , $userId);

$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->affected_rows;
$stmt->close();
```

After running the script it showing `0` affected rows. ( I am not getting any errors while running the script.)

Comment: does the update take place inside the db when you check?

Comment: @Ghost Nope db(field) still same empty

Comment: what are you really trying to do? update? or insert? if that row still doesn't exist then there will be no affected rows

Comment: Use $stmt->rowCount();